# Desktop application and OAuth?

Tags: c#, oauth, client, server

I have a server with Rest API. I want a C# Windows application to be a client.

Is it possible to use OAuth in this case?

I know that websites can access servers using OAuth but I'm not sure about desktop applications.

If it's not possible, what different solution would be good? If it's possible, do you know any examples or tutorials?

Comment: It's the language/framework that determines whether there is an OAuth library you can use, not whether it is desktop or web. There is an OAuth library for C# .NET with lots of tutorials. [OAuth library](http://oauth.net/code/) / [Tutorial](http://oauth.net/documentation/getting-started/)

Comment: So long as your desktop client has internet access to communicate with the providers, you should be fine. Have a look at the Google API client, this has an example for exactly what you're asking https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#installed-applications

Comment: Maybe the code about chapter 8 at: https://winrtexamples.codeplex.com/ could be useful